# Running docker-compose up with a different file spins up the same database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### **What I'm trying to do**

I normally start my postgres database (`local-db`) by running `docker-compose up` which by default relies on the `docker-compose.yml` file. In the same project directory I have also created a `docker-compose.data.yml` file. I'd like to use this second compose file to spin up a different database (`data-db`) for testing purposes when `local-db` is not running.

#### **What I've tried**

In docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/app.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
        read_only: true
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=local-db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: postgres-local-db
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres-local-db:
```

In docker-compose.data.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/app.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
        read_only: true
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=data-db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: postgres-data-db
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres-data-db:
```

Then I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.data.yml up`

#### **Expected results**

I want to spin up the `data-db` database specified in the `docker-compose.data.yml` file.

#### **Actual results**

`local-db` is spinned up again and trying to connect to `data-db` via PyCharm results in the error  `FATAL: database "data-db" does not exist`

Comment: Silly question... but you are killing the local-db before you bring up the data-db, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a wild guess but I think you either manually copied data from the `local-db` to the `data-db` or your first launch of the `data-db` container was with `POSTGRES_DB` variable set to `local-db`. `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_DB` only make sense when `PGDATA` contain no database, otherwise they're just ignored. You may test the theory by changing something in the `local-db` then querying the same value in `data-db`. This should clearly define if it is the same database or not.

If those two are actually different databases (as they should be) you may re-initialise the `data-db` container with this:

```
# destroy containers along with persistent data on volumes
docker-compose -f docker-compose.data.yml down -v
# then create anew
docker-compose -f docker-compose.data.yml up
```

This time it will respect `POSTGRES_DB` variable and create a database named `data-db`.

I also recommend you to add a `container_name` property to your database containers so you can easily differentiate them. This won't help with the problem at all but it will help you to understand which one is up.

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f